# "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

I've been trying to do a lookup on Power bi dax and this error keeps coming up "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.". Any idea how I can fix this?

Concurrence = LOOKUPVALUE(EMR[last drug pickup date],EMR[pepfarID],NDR[Patient Identifier])

Am Expecting the lookup to return the last drug pickup date

Comment: That must mean that at least one of the *Patient Identifier* entries from the *NDR* table occurs more than once in the *pepfarID* column of the *EMR* table. Which of the *last drug pickup date* entries do you want to return in such cases? Or will they all be the same date?